# How global variable works in parallel programming with Python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, global-variables

I have this code. In the sequential approach the message "no ok" is printed, while in the parallel approach the message ["ok", "ok", "ok"] is printed instead of the ["not ok", "not ok", "not ok"] that I expected.

How could I change variable globVar without giving it as argument in "test" function?

```
import multiprocessing

global globVar
globVar = 'ok'

def test(arg1):
    print(arg1)
    return globVar
    
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    globVar = 'not ok'

    #Sequential
    print(test(0))    
    
    #Parallel 
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    argList = [0,1,2]
    result = pool.map(test,argList)
    pool.close()
```

Comment: child processes load the script as an external module, so they ignore whatever is in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` bit. So they see `globVar` as it's defined outside of it, as `'ok'`

Comment: @AJ Biffl thank you for your answer. So I could only modify the value of the variable globVar if I give it as argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR.** You can skip to the last paragraph for the solution or read everything to understand what is actually going on.

You did not tag your question with your platform (e.g. `windows` or `linux`) as the guidelines for posting questions tagged with `multiprocessing` requests that you do; the behavior ("behaviour" for Anglos) of global variables very much depends on the platform.

On platforms that use method `spawn` to create new processes, such as Windows, to create and initialize each processes in the pool that is created with your `pool = multiprocessing.Pool()` statement, a new, empty address space is created and a new Python interpreter is launched that re-reads and re-executes the source program in order to initialize the address space before ultimately calling the worker function `test`. That means that every statement at global scope, i.e. import statements, variable declarations, function declarations, etc., are executed for this purpose. However, in the new subprocess variable `__name__` will *not* be "__main__" so any statements within the `if __name__ == "__main__" :` block will not be executed. That is why for Windows platforms you must put code that creates new processes within such a block. Failure to do so would result in an infinite recursive process-creation loop if it were to go otherwise undetected.

So if you are running under Windows, your main process has set `globVar` to 'not ok' just prior to creating the pool. But when the processes are initialized prior to calling `test`, your source is re-executed and each process, which *runs in its own address space and therefore has its own copy of `globVar` re-initialized that variable back to 'ok'.* *That* is the value that `test` will see and the previous statement implies that modifying that local copy of `globVar` will not be reflected back to the main process.

Now on platforms that use `fork` to create new processes, such as `Linux`, things are a bit different. When the subprocesses are created, each one inherits the address space of the parent process as read-only and only when it attempts to modify memory does it get a copy ("copy on write"). This is clearly a more efficient process-creating mechanism. So in this case `test` will see `globVar` having a value of 'not ok' because that was the value it had at the time the subprocesses were created. But if `test` updates `globVar`, the "copy on write" mechanism will ensure that it is updating a `globVar` that exists in a local address space. So again the main process will not see the updated value.

So having worker functions *returning* values as your `test` function is doing is a standard way of reflecting back to the main process results. **Your problem is that *you are not starting with a `globVar` value that you expected*.** This can be solved by initializing the pool's processes with the correct `globVar` value using the *initializer* and *initargs* arguments to the `Pool` constructor (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pool#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)):

```py
import multiprocessing

global globVar
globVar = 'ok'

def init_processes(gVar):
    global globVar
    globVar = gVar

def test(arg1):
    print(arg1)
    return globVar

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    globVar = 'not ok'

    #Sequential
    print(test(0))

    #Parallel
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=init_processes, initargs=(globVar,))
    argList = [0,1,2]
    result = pool.map(test,argList)
    pool.close()
    print(result)
```

Prints:

```
0
not ok
0
1
2
['not ok', 'not ok', 'not ok']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works and you helped me understand what was wrong.

Comment: The reason this example works is that you are having only one subprocess and the different/independent subprocesses are not manipulating a really global and unique variable. Therefore, there are still some problems.

Comment: @FarzadAmirjavid If you had multiple processes that needed to see changes to this variable in real time, then that would be a different story. But not this story, where the OP just wanted to have the change reflected back to the main process and thought that by changing a global variable that would be sufficient.

Comment: My answer is not in contradiction to your answer. I said if there are two parallel functions then there is another approach. The topic you talked is super interesting :-)

Answer (score 0):

On a windows machine, I tried a multiprocessing by which a global list variable is manipulated by some functions. In this example, the system is unable to manipulate the global variable. Actually, we are trying to add some new elements into a list by some functions and in a parallel manner; but the list is not filled finally:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support
import multiprocessing
global mylist
mylist = []
def f1(a):
    global mylist
    mylist.append(a)
    return mylist
def f2(a):
    global mylist
    mylist.append(a)
    return mylist
def f3(a):
    global mylist
    mylist.append(a)
    return mylist
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    freeze_support()
    r1 = pool.apply_async(f1,[1])
    r2 = pool.apply_async(f2,[2])
    r3 = pool.apply_async(f3,[3])
    r4 = pool.apply_async(f1,[4])
    r5 = pool.apply_async(f2,[5])
    r6 = pool.apply_async(f3,[6])
    a1 = r1.get(timeout=234)
    a2 = r2.get(timeout=234)
    a3 = r3.get(timeout=234)
    a4 = r4.get(timeout=234)
    a5 = r5.get(timeout=234)
    a6 = r6.get(timeout=234)
    print(mylist)
```

The output is:

```
[]
```

I analyze when you create multiprocessing, then memory is divided into completely separated/independent pieces or segments. And there is no shared memory between the processes. That is a fact with multiprocessing feature of Python. The main process declares a global variable, then the other three subprocesses would define three other global variables for their own scopes. However, the programmer sees one global variable.

But, no worries, here is a solution for the above-mentioned example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process,Manager
def f1(a):
    l = []
    l.append(a)
    return l
def f2(a):
    l = []
    l.append(a)
    return l
def f3(a):
    l = []
    l.append(a)
    return l
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    freeze_support()
    r1 = pool.apply_async(f1,[1])
    r2 = pool.apply_async(f2,[2])
    r3 = pool.apply_async(f3,[3])
    r4 = pool.apply_async(f1,[4])
    r5 = pool.apply_async(f2,[5])
    r6 = pool.apply_async(f3,[6])
    a1 = r1.get(timeout=234)
    a2 = r2.get(timeout=234)
    a3 = r3.get(timeout=234)
    a4 = r4.get(timeout=234)
    a5 = r5.get(timeout=234)
    a6 = r6.get(timeout=234)
    mylist = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6
    print(mylist)
```

The output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

The solution is that you need to wrap up the output of every parallel processing functions.

Actually, that is the only strategy that I found working with Python and when I tried the other methods such as multiprocessing Manager, but it did not work properly.